# isSameOrBefore implementation for date-fns

Tags: javascript, momentjs, date-fns

As moment is deprecated, I decided to stash moment from my entire project and thinking to use datefns as a replacement. While I was going through the code file, I came across a line which is saying,

```
moment(date1).isSameOrBefore(date2, year);
```

I started looking for something that is similar to what that function is doing but unfortunately, date-fns doesn't have anything to perform precision-based comparison (i.e: year, month or date comparison)? Can anyone suggest some workaround with date-fns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to create a drop-in replacement, as long as you test against the relevant moment function.

We can look for the relevant *startOfXXX* procedure to compare dates when the `unit` is specified, and also throw an error if it is missing:

```js
function isSameOrBefore(date1, date2, unit = '') {
    if (unit) {
        const procName = `startOf${unit[0].toUpperCase()}${unit.slice(1)}`;
        if (!dateFns[procName]) { 
            throw new Error(`isSameOrBefore: Unsupported unit: ${unit}`);
        }
        date1 = dateFns[procName](date1);
        date2 = dateFns[procName](date2);
    }
    return dateFns.isBefore(date1, date2) || dateFns.isEqual(date1, date2);
}

// Test against various inputs
const dts = ['2010-10-20 01:00', '2010-10-20 00:00', '2010-10-20 00:59:00', '2010-10-01', '2010-09-01', '2009-09-01'];
let units = ['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'minute'];
let dt1 = '2010-10-20 01:00'
let allTests = [];
for(let dt2 of dts) {
    for(let unit of units) {
        // Ensure we get the same answer as moment().isSameOrBefore
        const testPassed = isSameOrBefore(dt1, dt2, unit) === moment(dt1).isSameOrBefore(dt2, unit)
        allTests.push(testPassed);
        console.log(`isSameOrBefore(${dt1}, ${dt2}, ${unit}):`, isSameOrBefore(dt1, dt2, unit));
        console.log(`isSameOrBefore(${dt1}, ${dt2}, ${unit}): Test passed:`, testPassed ? "TRUE": "FALSE")
    }
}
console.log("All tests passed:", allTests.every(res => res) ? "TRUE": "FALSE")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/date-fns/1.30.1/date_fns.min.js" integrity="sha512-F+u8eWHrfY8Xw9BLzZ8rG/0wIvs0y+JyRJrXjp3VjtFPylAEEGwKbua5Ip/oiVhaTDaDs4eU2Xtsxjs/9ag2bQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: Everything seems good but importing entire dateFns. Hmm.

Answer (score 7):

You could use [`differenceInYears`](https://date-fns.org/v2.22.1/docs/differenceInYears):

```js
const date1 = new Date(2021, 6, 20);;
const date2 = new Date(2021, 7, 2);

function isSameOrBefore(date1, date2) {
  return dateFns.differenceInYears(date1, date2) <= 0;
}

console.log(isSameOrBefore(date1, date2));

console.log(isSameOrBefore(date1, new Date('2022-06-20')));

console.log(isSameOrBefore(date1, new Date('2019-06-20')));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/date-fns/1.28.5/date_fns.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What about days? @Fraction

Comment: you have [`differenceInDays`](https://date-fns.org/v2.22.1/docs/differenceInDays) and there are also other helpers that you can check in the [doc](https://date-fns.org/v2.22.1/docs/Getting-Started)

Answer (score 3):

Using `startOfSOMETHING()` you can check if a date is before or same using the minute, hour, day, month ecc to compare they.

```js
const dateBefore = dateFns.startOfHour(new Date(1988, 9, 26, 05, 35));
const dateSame = dateFns.startOfHour(new Date(1988, 9, 26, 11, 55));
const dateAfter = dateFns.startOfHour(new Date(1988, 9, 26, 16, 50));

const limit = dateFns.startOfHour(new Date(1988, 9, 26, 11, 55));

// dateBefore < limit => is before
if (dateFns.isBefore(dateBefore, limit) || dateFns.isEqual(dateBefore, limit)) console.log(dateFns.format(dateBefore), 'is before');
else console.log('is not before');

// dateSame === limit => is same
if (dateFns.isBefore(dateSame, limit) || dateFns.isEqual(dateSame, limit)) console.log(dateFns.format(dateSame), 'is same');
else console.log('is not same');

// dateAfter > limit =>  is after
if (dateFns.isBefore(dateAfter, limit) || dateFns.isEqual(dateAfter, limit)) console.log('you mustnt see that message ');
else console.log(dateFns.format(dateAfter), 'is after');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/date-fns/1.28.5/date_fns.min.js"></script>
```

In my opinion this library is awful, i prefer day.js that is very similar to moment.js or elaborate the date with `new Date()` of Javascritp.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`getYear`](https://date-fns.org/v2.22.1/docs/getYear) to get the "year" part of both dates first, then compare the two dates.

Something like:

```js
const date1 = new Date(2021, 6, 20);
const date2 = new Date(2021, 7, 2);
const date3 = new Date(2020, 1, 15);
console.log(dateFns.getYear(date1) <= dateFns.getYear(date2));
console.log(dateFns.getYear(date1) <= dateFns.getYear(date3));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/date-fns/1.28.5/date_fns.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import { isBefore, isEqual } from 'date-fns';

isSameOrBefore(date1: Date, date2: Date, property?: string) {
  switch (property) {
    case 'full':
      return isBefore(date1, date2) || isEqual(date1, date2);
    case 'year':
      return date1.getFullYear() <= date2.getFullYear();
    case 'month':
      return (
        isBefore(date1.getFullYear(), date2.getFullYear()) ||
        (isEqual(date1.getFullYear(), date2.getFullYear()) &&
          date1.getMonth() <= date2.getMonth())
      );
    case 'date':
      return (
        isBefore(date1.getFullYear(), date2.getFullYear()) ||
        (isEqual(date1.getFullYear(), date2.getFullYear()) &&
          date1.getMonth() < date2.getMonth()) ||
        (isEqual(date1.getFullYear(), date2.getFullYear()) &&
          isEqual(date1.getMonth(), date2.getMonth()) &&
          date1.getDate() <= date2.getDate())
      );
    default:
      return compareDesc(date1, date2);
  }
}
```

You can add more implementation for day, moment ....

Comment: Can you implement day also? Just for the sake of completion @Sang Dang

Comment: Sure, I just updated my comment @AshishBairwa

Answer (score 0):

Let me post an answer too. It doesn't require you to import entire date-fns

```
import { endOfDay, endOfWeek, endOfMonth, endOfYear } from 'date-fns';

export function isSameOrBefore(date1, date2, unit) {
    let method;
    switch (unit) {
        case 'day':
            method = endOfDay;
            break;
        case 'week':
            method = endOfWeek;
            break;
        case 'month':
            method = endOfMonth;
            break;
        case 'year':
            method = endOfYear;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    const startTimestamp = method ? method(date1): date1;
    return dateFns.isBefore(startTimestamp, date2) || dateFns.isEqual(startTimestamp, date2);
}
```